# Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfRenderer in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, pdf, xamarin, xamarin.android

Why can I not find the `PdfRenderer` class in the `Android.Graphics.Pdf` namespace in Xamarin?

It is there in the Documentation:

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Pdf.PdfRenderer/

```
using Android.Graphics.Pdf;

private PdfRenderer mPdfRenderer;
```

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name `PdfRenderer' could not be
>   found. Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246) (TestAPDF)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PdfRenderer` class was added in Android Api Level 21 (Lollipop). Which version of Android are you targeting in your project? You need to set [Target Framework](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/understanding_android_api_levels/#framework) to Api Level 21 for the class to be available.

Comment: I am using target e minimum 23. Thanks for reply.

Comment: @Zamby: Do you mean Target Android Version or Target Framework ?

Comment: Both target and minimum are 23.

Comment: Sorry, Target Android is 23. Where is Target Framework?

Comment: @Zamby: On the properties pane of the project. Did you check the link in my answer?